# HTML pattern for input that allows only numbers with maximum of 1 dot or (1 or 2 spaces)

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I am trying to create pattern in angular for input to allow only numbers with 1 dot or (1 or 2 spaces) i.e. it should allow

1. Decimal Degrees like 45 or 34.1234 or -91.5
2. Degrees Minutes like 12 13
3. Degrees Minutes Seconds like 12 13 5

`<input type="text" required pattern="/^[\d](\.| )?[\d]( )?[\d]">`

I am looking for pattern in above code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

as per the [documentation for the HTML pattern-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern)

you shouldn't use the usual JavaScript/PHP/etc.

```
/^$/ delimiters
```

as pattern assumes

```
^(?: at the beginning and )$ at the end
```

ie.

```
pattern="[a-z]"
```

will accept all inputs containing only lowercase a-z characters

so here's a full pattern regexp that will do what you ask

```
pattern="(-)?\d{1,}|(-)?\d{1,}(\.)\d{1,}|(-)?\d{1,}(\s)(-)?\d{1,}|(-)?\d{1,}(\s)(-)?\d{1,}(\s)(-)?\d{1,}"
```

explanation:

```
(-)? optional negative sign
\d{1,} matches any number (ie. 3 or 235 but not 3.7)
| or
\d{1,} matches any number 
(\.)\d{1,} followed by a single period followed by a number (ie. 4.34 or 5.98 but not 3.1.4 or 43..2)
| or
\d{1,} matches any number 
(\s)\d{1,} followed by a single space followed by a number (ie. 3 5 or 654 34 but not 3 1 4 or 43  2)
| or
\d{1,} matches any number 
(\s)\d{1,} followed by a single space followed by a number 
(\s)\d{1,} followed by a single space followed by a number (ie. 5 2 65 or 543 23 1 but not 23 32 45 654 or 876  65  34)
// (-)? optional negative sign
// {1,} values can be more than 1 character (required or it will only accept single digits ie. 3 or 5.6 or 7 5 or 8 4 6 but not 43 or 23.46 or 12 76 or 35 65 78)
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="numbers">number or number with decimals or 2-3 numbers seperated by 1 space</label>
  <input id="numbers" name="numbers" required pattern="(-)?\d{1,}|(-)?\d{1,}(\.)\d{1,}|(-)?\d{1,}(\s)(-)?\d{1,}|(-)?\d{1,}(\s)(-)?\d{1,}(\s)(-)?\d{1,}">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```